# How to rotate a camera around obj wavefront file contents?

Tags: python, blender

I have an .obj file. I do not know it’s contents bounding box before hand. I want to load it into blender and rotate camera around it in "K"th frames (e.g. 15 frames). How to do such a thing in blender using python api?

Comment: Take a look here: (or ask there) [blender.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to do an object turnaround is to add an empty and make it the parent of the camera, animating the z-rotation of the empty will then rotate the camera around the object, you can give the camera a trackto constraint so that the camera always points at the target object.

You can use the objects [`bound_box`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.bound_box) to find its outer limits, then add a bit more so the object stays inside the view and position the camera with that. Making the extra distance proportional to the object size should work for most objects.

The addon I made for [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14188/935) shows how to make a bounding box around multiple objects, which may be helpful if you have multiple objects at once.

To do that in python -

```
import bpy
scn = bpy.context.scene

bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath='obj1.obj')
target = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
scn.objects.active = target
# centring the origin gives a better bounding box and rotation point
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')

cam_x_pos = max([v[0] for v in target.bound_box]) * 2.5
cam_y_pos = max([v[1] for v in target.bound_box]) * 2.5
cam_z_pos = max([v[2] for v in target.bound_box]) * 2.5

rot_centre = bpy.data.objects.new('rot_centre', None)
scn.objects.link(rot_centre)
rot_centre.location = target.location

camera = bpy.data.objects.new('camera', bpy.data.cameras.new('camera'))
scn.objects.link(camera)
camera.location = (cam_x_pos, cam_y_pos, cam_z_pos)
camera.parent = rot_centre
m = camera.constraints.new('TRACK_TO')
m.target = target
m.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
m.up_axis = 'UP_Y'

rot_centre.rotation_euler.z = 0.0
rot_centre.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', index=2, frame=1)
rot_centre.rotation_euler.z = radians(360.0)
rot_centre.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', index=2, frame=101)
# set linear interpolation for constant rotation speed
for c in rot_centre.animation_data.action.fcurves:
    for k in c.keyframe_points:
        k.interpolation = 'LINEAR'
scn.frame_end = 100
```

Comment: I modified radians(360.0) to math.radians(360.0), what's the effect of above codes? Shall I expect a couple of pictures? Or just camera rotate objects without shooting pictures? What about if I want camera shooting some pictures saved as jped or png?

Comment: The code imports an obj and animates a camera rotating around the object, it is set to take 100 frames to go around, it only creates the animation. If you then render the animation, you will get 100 images or a 100 frame video of the turnaround. You may also go to a specific frame/s and render one or more images if you choose. See [`bpy.ops.render.render`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html?highlight=render#bpy.ops.render.render) to automate rendering, set `write_still=True` if you are only rendering single frames.