# Taking an image of an entire model with the Blender Python API

Tags: python, blender

We are trying to take an image of an entire model (not very large models) with the Blender Python API. The problem we're having seems to be re positioning the camera in the right spot. Now we get an image from inside the object (like this - http://prntscr.com/k4sekc). And when we try to move a camera further away we just get a black image.

I think the solution may involve finding the "bounding box" of the object, and moving away a little bit from it at a certain angle, and taking the picture that way. Does that make sense?

My apologies for not posting code, I can maybe add some later if someone has ideas, but I am not the developer dealing with this issue directly so I don't have that code right now. I'm searching around the API docs for a solution and figured some of the folks here could probably help.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing all this with python?

Comment: @SuperStew I suppose the reason for us starting/attempting to do this using python is because that is a potential solution that we found. Do you have an alternative? I am certainly open to it!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50500803/2684771) should do what you want.

Comment: @sambler yes! I saw that and thought the same and pushed it along to the developers. Thanks much for your addition :)

Comment: @nerk looks like you found a solution, i guess i was just wondering why you weren't just positioning the camera in blender through the UI

Comment: @SuperStew because this python script will run on a web server and provide images for an application.