# Blender Command line importing files

Tags: blender

I will run the script on the Blender command line. All I want to do is run the same script for several files. I have completed the steps to run a background file (.blend) and run a script in Blender, but since I have just loaded one file, I can not run the script on another file.

I looked up the Blender manual, but I could not find the command to import the file.

I proceeded to creating a .blend file and running the script.

blender -b background.blend -P pythonfile.py

In addition, if possible, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to script the camera and track axes to track to contraint (Ctrl + T -> Track to constraint).

really thank you for reading my ask.

Answer (score 0):

Blender can only have one blend file open at a time, any open scripts are cleared out when a new file is opened. What you want is a loop that starts blender for each blend file using the same script file.

On *nix systems you can use a simple shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

for BF in $(ls *.blend)
do
    blender -b ${BF} -P pythonfile.py
done
```

A more cross platform solution is to use python -

```
from glob import glob
from subprocess import call

for blendFile in glob('*.blend'):
    call([ 'blender',
    '-b', blendFile,
    '--python', 'pythonfile.py' ])
```

To add a [Track-to](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.TrackToConstraint.html) constraint to `Camera` pointing it at `Cube` -

```
camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
c = camera.constraints.new('TRACK_TO')
c.target = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
c.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
c.up_axis = 'UP_Y'
```

This is taken from my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50500803/2684771) which also animates the camera going around the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = CameraObject

bpy.ops.object.constraint_add(type='TRACK_TO')

CameraObject.constraints["Track To"].target = bpy.data.objects['ObjectToTrack']
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide some context and explanation of how this code answeres the question.